# delete parent element upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#add').click(function () {
                let task = $('<div class="task"></div>');
                let name_des = $('<div class="name_description"></div>');
                let name = $('<div class="name"></div>');
                name.append('<div id="taskName"></div>', '<div id="taskTime"></div>');
                name_des.append(name, '<div class="description"></div>');
                task.append('<input type="checkbox">', name_des, '<small id="delete">Delete</small>');
                $('#taskCont').append(task);
            });

            $('#delete').click(function (){
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
```

```css
#taskCont{
  /* background: yellow; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.task{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.task:not(:first-child){
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.task > *{
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.task > *:not(:nth-child(2)){
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.name_description{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20px;
}
.name_description *{
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.name{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.name > *{
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="taskCont"></div>
```

In this code why the delete button not working? How can I delete the parent element here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to attach event on dynamically created element, try using *delegation approach* that uses jQuery's [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/). This will attach events to elements that are added to the DOM at a later time.

Change:

```
$('#delete').click(function (){
```

To:

```
$('body').on('click', '#delete', function (){
```

```js
$('#add').click(function () {
  let task = $('<div class="task"></div>');
  let name_des = $('<div class="name_description"></div>');
  let name = $('<div class="name"></div>');
  name.append('<div id="taskName"></div>', '<div id="taskTime"></div>');
  name_des.append(name, '<div class="description"></div>');
  task.append('<input type="checkbox">', name_des, '<small id="delete">Delete</small>');
  $('#taskCont').append(task);
});

$('body').on('click', '#delete', function (){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
#taskCont{
  /* background: yellow; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.task{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.task:not(:first-child){
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.task > *{
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.task > *:not(:nth-child(2)){
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.name_description{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20px;
}
.name_description *{
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.name{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.name > *{
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="taskCont"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should attach the click event dynamically. Live may be a good choice. Try this.

```html
$(selector).live( eventName, function(){} );
```

Comment: You should not use that as *This API has been removed in jQuery 1.9*....https://api.jquery.com/live/